# Ubuntu stuck in boot - recovering journal

Tags: boot

I am getting the error ubuntu stuck in recovery journal
I have tried the following from a live disk, but no luck.

Any recommendation?

Let's check/repair your file system...

```
boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T
type sudo fdisk -l
identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
type sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5, replacing sdXX with the number you found earlier
repeat the fsck command if there were errors
type reboot
```

I also tried on sda1. It said dirty bit set, so I cleaned it. I am seeing boot stuck on /dev/sda5 clean

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is 20.04 - I had been using it headless. I am currently removing nvidia from recovery mode and then reinstall nvidia or base graphics drivers. I have a hope. haha

Comment: Pretty hard to offer any good advice if you are not even sure what version you are using.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure it's ubuntu 20.04. I can report back once I have this nvidia drivers removal and reinstall takes place. I booted into recovery mode and uninstalled nvidia drivers and reboot the pc. I saw ubuntu splash screen, but then nothing, so I am re-installing drivers in recovery mode to see if that helps.